# Homebrew install problem - "Can't download the software because of a network problem"

Tags: macos, network, homebrew

When trying to install Homebrew, I'm getting the following issue notification: "Can't download the software because of a network problem".

Despite the suggestion of a network problem, I do have a network connection and it works fine for anything else I want to do.

I was running the following script to install Homebrew (as suggested on the website):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

I did find a similar problem on this site, but it is still not working for me: [Boot Camp - Can't download the software because of a network problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164851/boot-camp-cant-download-the-software-because-of-a-network-problem) .
My MacBook Pro is an Apple M1 Pro model.

Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? Is this a fresh install or did you migrate from a previous computer where Homebrew or other Unix binaries have already been installed manually? Is this your own network or are you using a corporate/university/coffee shop network for this? What exactly is the error, can you please copy/paste both the command you run and all the output you get into the question, **as text**?

Comment: Also, run `curl -v -o /dev/null https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh` and again copy/paste into the question. This will show more details about the connection and any issues which may come up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems it's an overall problem on my macbook pro M1. I can't update to the newest version of macOS ventura either. The error I receive is the following: "An error occurred while installing the selected updates.". If I try to reinstall macOS Monterey, I'm getting the following error: "The recovery server could not be contacted". I'm no Apple genius so I have no idea whether the Homebrew problem from above, and downloading the updates are connected. To answer your questions: it is a fresh install of Homebrew, version 12.3.1 macOS Monterey, it is my own network.

Comment: The following site https://osxdaily.com/2021/01/27/fix-macos-installation-failed-an-error-occurred-while-installing-the-selected-updates-errors/ covers the problem and suggests some solutions however, Apple servers are not down, rebooting does not work, I'm not enrolled in beta updates (as far as i know), and i'm connected to the internet. I don't trust the website enough to install the software package from that site directly - using the appstore, i'm getting the same error. So, not sure what exactly to do except to "wait a bit". Any thoughts?

Comment: This seems to be a general problem then, not sure whether it's related or not. Nevertheless it would help to run the verbose curl from my second output, maybe the log output gives more insights.

Comment: Also, do you have any content blockers, router-level firewalls, PiHoles or similar in your network?

Comment: I can't post the output as it is too lang, is there something specific you are looking for? This would be the beginning:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 2606:50c0:8001::154:443...
* Connected to raw.githubusercontent.com (2606:50c0:8001::154) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:

Comment: No content blockers, router-level firewalls, PiHoles on my network as far as I know

Comment: Please **edit** the question, paste the text at the bottom (and format as code, but than I can do afterwards if you don't know how to do it).

Comment: You're not running Little Snitch, or LuLu, or anything like that?

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help! I've got it running now. It seemed my installassistant was broken.. downloaded a new one and everything is working again (including updating my OS)

Comment: Please post an answer explaining what you did to solve the problem, it might help others in the future.

Comment: I used the link on this website: https://osxdaily.com/where-download-macos-installers/ in order to download the update to MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 which contained an installAssistant.pkg. After this was done, I was able to update and install Homebrew properly.